# How to make Placeholder text appear instead of Value text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a form that lets people input a URL in a text field that has a value and a different placeholder text. I want the placeholder to show up instead of the value so if they don't type anything in the field it goes to the original field, but the links are very long so I don't want those to show up in the field.

I am using an input field with the value the url for a specific LinkedIn profile but I would like to have a placeholder to show LinkedIn's homepage url as it is much shorter.

```
<input 
  id="linkedIn" 
  type="text" 
  value="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow" 
  placeholder="https://www.linkedin.com">
```

I am seeing only the value and not the placeholder text showing in the input field. I would like to see the placeholder instead of the value.

Comment: The `value` determines what is in the input field and the `placeholder` will never show if there is some value in the field. Why do you want to store the URL specifically in the input value beforehand if you want users to be able to input something else?

Comment: Can we see the javascript code handling this input?

Comment: @Yannick Because some of the people who would be filling out this form are a bit older and might not know to delete stuff in the form or may delete stuff on accident. I am trying to make this as easy and foolproof as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS code to verify the value of input field. Then if the textbox be empty it will get he original field.

```
<input 
id="linkedIn" 
type="text" 
placeholder="https://www.linkedin.com">
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="myFunction()">

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var linkedIn = document.getElementById("linkedIn");
        if(linkedIn.value == ""){
            linkedIn.value = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow";
        }
    }
</script>
```